# How to filter specific record related to same model after clicking on stat button

Tags: python, odoo

## in registration.school model

```
def action_count_student(self):
    return {
        'name': 'action',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form,search',
        'res_model': 'registration.student',
        'res_id': self.id,
        }
```

## xml file for registration.school model

```
<div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
                    <button class="oe_stat_button" type="object"  name="action_count_student" icon="fa-graduation-cap" >
                        <field name="count" string="Student" widget="statinfo"/>
                    </button>
                    <button class="oe_stat_button" type="object"  name="action_count_teacher" icon="fa-teacher" >
                        <field name="count_teacher" string="Teacher" widget="statinfo"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

It is displaying student count present in registration.student table.
But after clicking the stat button it should show student data related to that school only. because there is one2many relation between school and student. But it is showing all the records of students present in student model. How to solve it. anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add domain to filter record in your action

```py
 @api.multi  
 def action_count_student(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        return {
            'name': 'action',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form', # and remove search because it appears automatically in searchable view like tree view 
            'res_model': 'registration.student',
            # id don't know the name of m2o in student registration is assumed it's school_id
            'domain': [('school_id', '=', self.id)],  
            'res_id': self.id,
            }
```